# How to merge arraylist element?

Tags: java

I have  `a string example = "this site holds all the examples from The Java Developers Almanac and more. Copy and paste these examples directly into your applications"

after token and do some i want on string example  i have arraylist like :

```
ArrayList <token > arl = " "this site holds ", "holds all the examples ", "the examples from The Java Developers", " Copy and paste " )
```

"this site holds ", i know position start and end in string test : star = 1 end = 3
" holds all the examples ", i know position  stat = 3 end = 6, 
 "the examples from The Java Developers", i know position  stat = 5 end =10,
 "Copy and paste" i know position  stat = 14 end = 17,

we can see,some element in arl overlaping :"this site holds ","holds all the examples ","the examples from The Java Developers".

The problem here is how can i merge overlaping element to recived arraylist like

ArrayList  result ="" this site holds all the examples from The Java Developers","" Copy and paste"";

Here my code : but it only merge fist elecment if check is element overloaping

```
public ArrayList<TextChunks> finalTextChunks(ArrayList<TextChunks> textchunkswithkeyword) {
        ArrayList<TextChunks > result = (ArrayList<TextChunks>) textchunkswithkeyword.clone();
            //System.out.print(result.size());
            int j;
            for(int i=0;i< result.size() ;i++) {
                int index = i;
                if(i+1>=result.size()){
                    break;
                }
                j=i+1;
                if(result.get(i).checkOverlapingTwoTextchunks(result.get(j))== true) {
                    TextChunks temp = new TextChunks();
                    temp = handleOverlaping(textchunkswithkeyword.get(i),textchunkswithkeyword.get(j),resultSearchEngine);
                    result.set(i, temp);
                    result.remove(j);
                    i = index;
                    continue;
            }
        }
        return result;  
    }
}
```

Thanks in avadce

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what you're asking for. Could you clarify your question? Perhaps by using a sample string that doesn't look like part of a question?

Comment: Sory because my english weak, i have been edit my question , hope you can understand !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do it or at least illustrates an idea for merging the chunks. Basically I'm destroying the existing chunks and recreate new ones. Sounds horrible but simplifies a lot. I just store the words in a List and iterate over that word list to build new (merged!) chunks.

```
private List<TextChunks> finalTextChunks(List<TextChunks> textchunkswithkeyword) {

   private List<TextChunks> result = new ArrayList<TextChunk>();
   private List<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>();

   // store all words in an arraylist, words are stored at their correct positions,
   // ignored words from the original text are represented by null entries
   for (TextChunks chunk : textchunkswithkeyword) {
     int start = chunk.getStartTextchunks();
     List<Token> tokens = chunk.getTokens(); // TODO - implement getTokens() in TextChunks class
     for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
        wordList.set(start+i, tokens.get(i).toString()); // TODO - overwrite toString() in Token class
     }
   }

   // recreate the chunks
   int start = 0;
   boolean isChunk = false;
   StringBuilder chunkBuilder;

   for (int i = 0; i < wordList.size(); i++) {
     String word = wordList.get(i);
     if (word == null) {
       if (isChunk) {
         // end of chunk detected
         TextChunk chunk = new TextChunk(chunkBuilder.toString().split(" "), start, i);
         result.add(chunk);
         isChunk = false;
       } else {
         // do nothing
       }
     } else {
       if (isChunk) {
         // chunk gets longer by one word
         chunkBuilder.append(" ").append(word);
       } else {
         // new chunk starts here
         chunkBuilder = new StringBuilder(word);
         start = i;
         isChunk = true;
       }
   }
   if (isChunk) {
     // create and add the last chunk
     TextChunks chunk = new TextChunk(chunkBuilder.toString(), start, wordList.size()-1);
     result.add(chunk);
   }
   return result;
}
```

(Warning - absolutely not tested, I have neither an IDE nor a compiler at hand)

**EDIT**

changed the code - you said, that the TextChunk class holds a token (words?) array. It was just three simple modifications.

**EDIT 2**

Final edit - I partially adapted my code to your classes. What *you* need to do:

1. implement a getTokens() method in TextChunks that simply returns the `arrt` field
2. implement a TextChunks constructor that takes a String (with space-separated words), the start and the end. Your `Token` class already provides a static method to convert the String in an arraylist of tokens
3. overwrite toString() method in `Token` class so that simply returns the token String.

Comment: Thanks for your help , but i think, your way can't help me .

My application have two class :

- Class token { String }
a Token is a string : in this class have some method like :
remove space, make arraytoken from string .
- Class textchunk {array token . int start , int end }
class textchunk extend token have array token and two value start and end .


So inside Textchunk is array token (string)

Comment: You can see my code for understand thing i can't explan clearly

!

Comment: @tiendv - I've seen, you've removed your positive vote from my answer. It's somewhat frustrating because it took quite a while understanding your question and your code and providing a practical solution. What did you expect?

Comment: @Andreas : I don't mean  that, because my mouse have problem when it move in srceen and click in that positive and i show "
Your vote is now locked in
unless this answer is edited
(click on this box to dismiss) " I don't know how to repair it . 

Hope you understand !

Thanks for your help ! I try to got your idea for fix my proplem !

Comment: @tiendv - *smile* - no problem, sorry for that misunderstanding, it just confused me bit ;) I edited my answer so you can - if you want - vote again. Good luck with your project! :-))